# Trouble with Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.4.3

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, maui

I've just update Visual Studio 2022 from version **17.4.2** to **17.4.3**.

Now it always displays:

> "The program '[17424] TEST.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

> The program '[17424] TEST.exe' has exited with code 2147942405 (0x80070005)."

...when starting to run debugging on my Windows machine (my computer is running Windows 10 Pro - 19044.2251).

Notice: I've just running default template Maui application (for .NET 7) of Visual Studio 20022 - like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="TEST.MainPage">

<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Spacing="25"
        Padding="30,0"
        VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Image
            Source="dotnet_bot.png"
            SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
            HeightRequest="200"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Label
            Text="Hello, World!"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
            FontSize="32"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Label
            Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
            SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
            FontSize="18"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Button
            x:Name="CounterBtn"
            Text="Click me"
            SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
            Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

It's OK if application is using .NET 6 - but fails if .NET 7 for Windows or Android platform is used (that I've checked).

Comment: It's new default template of Visualstudio 2022 for .Net7 - targeting to Windows - IOS - Adroid

Comment: It's fails in Windows.

Comment: Fails how exactly? Perhaps .Net 7 is simply not installed on the target machine?

Comment: @Ari0nhh: Fails 100%; I've test for both .Net 6.0(It's OK) and 7.0; Otherwise my recent app now was running OK on my computer with .Net 7.0 - with Visualstudio version 17.4.2 --> but fails after updated to 17.4.3

Comment: Note that visual studio installer now have a roll back button. It's faster than a reinstall. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-visual-studio-rollback/

Comment: @DragandDrop: I've tried to rollback to 17.4.2 - but it's still have troube like described. So now I trying to reinstall VS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'v found this: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12080

Install Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime 1.2 redist, it's solved trouble.

Comment: This solved for me as well.

Comment: This worked for me too. One of the things that was confusing was thinking that the runtime would be installed with the SDK - like how the .NET SDK includes the runtime. However, I had to explicitly install just the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue on Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.3. You can refer to the thread on github [MAUI apps crash on launch on Windows after Visual Studio update](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12080) for more information.

This might be an answer for you, you can check this comment link [Running the app as admin](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12080#issuecomment-1351322492). Another way to fix the problem is that you can roll back to the version 17.4.2.

Comment: I've try lauching VS as admin but It's still the same.